# How to install tfs in android studio?

Tags: tfs, android-studio-3.0

I want to use git and visual studio team services in android studio .. i can't install its plugin .. i searched in plugins in AS but nothing also tried to install plugin from disk but get this error

```
fail to load plugin descriptor from file
```

Also i tried to find browse repository but i can't find it in last version of AS

How can i achieve that?

This is my dependencies in build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation project(':baseGameUtils')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? How did you install the plugin?

Comment: How's your issue going?

Answer (score 0):

[Azure DevOps Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops) is working with Git and TFVC repositories on Azure DevOps and Team Foundation Server (TFS) 2015+ inside IntelliJ, Android Studio, and various other JetBrains IDEs. It is supported on Linux, Mac OS X, and Windows. It is compatible with IntelliJ IDEA Community and Ultimate editions (version 2018.3+) and Android Studio (version 3.4+). Please check your TFS version and Android Studio version.

You can install the plugin from Android Studio by browsing the Plugin Repository, or download the plugin to disk from the [Android Studio Plugin Repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7981-azure-devops) and install the downloaded JAR file.

Check the following link for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/java/download-android-studio-plug-in?view=azure-devops